# How to get ContourPlot over non rectangular region

Tags: plotting

How to get the following `ContourPlot`

```
ContourPlot[4 (s + i) -  Log[s] +  Log[i], {s, 0, 1}, {i, 0, 1}]
```

over a non rectangular region? First try

```
ContourPlot[4 (s + i) - Log[s] + Log[i], 
 Element[{s, i}  ,  {s > 0 && i > 0 && s + i < 1}]]
```

does not work.

Comment: For your first try, wrap the region condition with `ImplicitRegion`: `ContourPlot[4 (s + i) - Log[s] + Log[i], Element[{s, i}, ImplicitRegion[{s > 0 && i > 0 && s + i < 1}, {s, i}]]]`, but this is considerably slower and disables the refinement option `PlotPoints`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a region of the form $a \le x \le b$, $f(x) \le y \le g(x)$, one can use

```
ContourPlot[eqn, {x, a, b}, {y, f[x], g[x]}]
```

In the OP's case:

```
ContourPlot[4 (s + i) - Log[s] + Log[i], {s, 0, 1}, {i, 0, 1 - s}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Try the `RegionFunction` option:

```
ContourPlot[4 (s + i) - Log[s] + Log[i], {s, 0, 1}, {i, 0, 1}, 
 RegionFunction -> (#1 + #2 < 1 &)]
```

[image]